# use inner join on three table and aggregation in a single query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

I have three models,

```
class A(models.Model):
    code=models.CharField(max_length=9,unique=True)

class B(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(D)
    a = models.OneToOneField(A)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70,blank=True,default='')


class C(models.Model):
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    status_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

I need to query such that i can get code(from model A), name(from model B)   and status time (from model C) and status(from model C) where  submitted_by_id=1 and status should be maximum for each id.

The sql is :

```
SELECT A.code ,B.name,C.status,C.status_time FROM `A`  INNER JOIN  `B`  on A.id=B.a_id INNER JOIN  `C`  on A.id=C.a_id where B.submitted_by_id=1 and C.status_time=(se lect max(C.status_time) from `C` pipeline where C.a_id=A.id)
```

if any one can help me with the django ORM.
I am not able to understand how can i use inner joins,aggregation and subquery together in a single query.

EDIT:

```
B.objects.filter(submitted_by_id=1).values('name','a__code','a__c__status_time','a__c__status').order_by('-a__c__status').first()
```

I tried this query.But it return only one row  i.e. row with max status. 
Can we modify this and return the result for each id.

Comment: Still looking for the answer. I need this query to create a datatable view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use Django ORM like SQL. If I understand you correctly in Django ORM your query will look like:

```
result = []
bs = B.objects.filter(submitted_by_id=1)
for b in bs:
    a = b.a
    c = C.objects.filter(a=a).order_by('-status').first()
    result.append([a.code, b.name, c.status, c.status_time])
```

Comment: thnx. It works. But i need to do this in a single query. I have tried sql and it works fine.even your answer is perfect. But if you can help me do this in a single query. If it is not possible please explain why

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible, because in Django ORM you can't `JOIN` different models. You can however use `connection` object and execute a raw `SQL` query. Here's a link to docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors

Comment: I updated my question with an edit. may be if you could work around or else i will accept your answer and move forward.It would be better if you can advice on raw SQL for this.

Comment: I can't vouch for that but you can try: `[[obj[0], obj[1], max(obj[2]), obj[3][obj[2].index(max(obj[2]))]] for obj in B.objects.filter(submitted_by_id=1).values('name','a__code','a__c__status_time','a__c__status').order_by('-a__c__status')]`

Comment: what are your key names? are they `'name'`, `'a__code'`, `'a__c__status_time'` and `'a__c__status'`?

Comment: This is just an idea, Django is not really meant for such things but maybe replacing the numbers with keys will give you the result you need. Like `obj['name'], obj['a__code'], max(obj['a__c__status']), obj['a__c__status_time'][obj['a__c__status'].index(max(obj['a__c__status']))]`

Comment: Sorry.But it doesnt work. I think i should move forward with your 1st answer. And i can look into this issue later. Thnx for your help.

Comment: I am using this for datatable view. and for that i need to return a queryset object, but this gives a list. any comments on that?

Comment: You can fake a queryset with a `list` of `dict`s. So depending on what names of columns you need, you do something like that: `[{'code': obj[0], 'name': obj[1], 'status': obj[2], 'status_time': obj[3]} for obj in result]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the follow can help:

```
results = []
b_set = B.objects.filter(submitted_by__id=1)
for b in b_set:
    c = C.objects.filter(a__b=b).order_by('-status_time').first()
    results.append([c.a.code, c.a.b.name, c.status, c.status_time])
```

Comment: I want to do  this in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to do what you want.

I have not tested this at all, but here's what I would try:

```
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models import Max

annotated_c = C.objects.annotate(last_status_time=Max('a__cs__status_time'))
last_c = annotated_c.filter(status_time=F('last_status_time'),
                            a__b__submitted_by_id=1)

for c in last_c.select_related('a', 'a__b'):
    print c.a.code, c.a.b.name, c.status_time
```

You might need to add `related_name` to the foreign keys.

Set the `django.db` logger to `DEBUG` level to see exactly what SQL you are generating.

Comment: there is one more condition where he wants to filter on "submitted_by_id"=1. May be you can add this too.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @FullOfQuestions, I've now added the missing filter.